# Need to get the Checked input and checkbox value using jquery in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

[image: Screenshot]

Am having table data (retrieve data from mysql table and fetch in to table). table contains several records.I want to display checked checkbox value with input box value and checkbox when i clicking button in php. Checked checkbox value and checked input has deen displayed correctly using join function. but checked  with checkbox is not showing correctly. In my code, when i clicking button all checked check values are displayed. my problem to display only checked checkbox with checkbax using join function.

My table:

```
   <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1" width="500" class="tblListForm">
    <tr class="listheader">
    <td></td>
   <td>Username</td>
   <td>First Name</td>
   <td>Last Name</td>
   <td>Permissions</td>
   <td>CRUD Actions</td>
   </tr>
   <?php
      $i=0;
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       if($i%2==0)
       $classname="evenRow";
        else
       $classname="oddRow";
          ?>
       <tr class="<?php if(isset($classname)) echo $classname;?>">
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chk_id" name="chk_id" id="chk_id" value="<?php  echo $row["userId"]; ?>" /></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["userName"]; ?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="firstName" class="firstName" id="firstName" value="<?php echo $row["firstName"];?>" /></td>
       <td><?php echo $row["lastName"]; ?></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="grant" class="grant" id="grant" value="Y" /></td>
       <td><a href="edit_user.php?userId=<?php echo $row["userId"]; ?>" class="link"><img alt='Edit' title='Edit' src='images/edit.png' width='15px' height='15px' hspace='10' /></a>  <a href="delete_user.php?userId=<?php echo $row["userId"]; ?>"  class="link"><img alt='Delete' title='Delete' src='images/delete.png' width='15px' height='15px'hspace='10' /></a></td>
            </tr>
       <?php
       $i++;
       }
        ?>
      </table>
         <input type="button"  id="save_value" name="save_value" value="Save" />
```

my jquery code what i have tried:

```
   $('#save_value').click(function () {
            alert("Checkbox running");
                var chk_id = [];
                 var firstName = [];
                  var grant = [];


                 $.each($("input[ id='chk_id']:checked"), function () {
                      chk_id.push($(this).val());
                      firstName.push($(this).parent().parent().find("#firstName").val()); 
                       grant.push($(this).parent().parent().find($("#grant").is(':checked'));
                });

                alert(chk_id);
                alert(firstName);
                alert(grant);
            });
```

Here,

am getting checked checkbox and checked input value. my problem to dispaly the checked checkbox with check value.

Thanks@

Comment: its working got output

Comment: Classes can be shared by lots of HTML elements i.e lots of HTML Elements can have the same class but ID's are something else ID's can't be shared by elements but for each element ID is going to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You made a few small mistakes:

- You can't have multiple elements with the same ID, IDs must be unique. So I removed all duplicate IDs from your HTML (`id="chk_id"`,`id="firstName"`,`id="grant"`) and in your JS, used the classes instead.
- You missed a closing bracket in `grant.push($(this).parent().parent().find($(".grant").is(':checked')));`.
- `.find($(".grant").is(':checked'))` isn't working as you expect, and also not necessary.
  Use this instead: `.find(".grant:checked")`.
- And finally, the reason why your alert showed two values whether the checkboxes were checked or not: `grant.push( ... );` always pushes something into the array, if the jQuery-selector matched nothing and would return `false`, that value would still be pushed into the array.
  In fact, if you correct all three points above, and don't check the permission checkbox, the value in the array will be `undefined`. If you do check the box, it will be `Y`.

  So, in order to make it work, you just have to put the `grant.push( ... );` inside an if-clause, where you check for `".grant:checked"`:
  `if ($p.find(".grant:checked").length) {grant.push($p.find(".grant:checked").val());}`

  *- `$p` stands for `$(this).parent().parent()`, I stored a reference in a `var`.*
  *- `.length` checks if the length of the returned object is greater than `0`. Without it, the if-clause would still always be `true`, because jQuery still returns an object (with value `undefined`).*

See **code snippet** below for a demo:

```js
$('#save_value').click(function() {
  var chk_id=[], firstName=[], grant=[];
  
  $.each($("input[class='chk_id']:checked"),function() {
    var $row = $(this).parent().parent();
    chk_id.push($(this).val());
    firstName.push($row.find(".firstName").val()); 
    if ($row.find(".grant:checked").length) {grant.push($row.find(".grant:checked").val());}
  });
  
  console.log(chk_id, firstName, grant);
});
```

```css
table,input[type=button] {float:left;} /*ONLY SO console.log() DOESN'T COVER BUTTON*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="tblListForm">
  <tr class="listheader"><td></td><td>Username</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Permissions</td></tr>
  
  <tr class="evenRow">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chk_id" name="chk_id" value="4" /></td>
    <td>sardhar</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="firstName" class="firstName" value="sardhar" /></td>
    <td>mohamed</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="grant" class="grant" value="Y" /></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr class="oddRow">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chk_id" name="chk_id" value="3" /></td>
    <td>fg</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="firstName" class="firstName" value="vb" /></td>
    <td>vb</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="grant" class="grant" value="Y" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" id="save_value" name="save_value" value="Save" />
```

**jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3utno9at/**